# Open File explorer from command line in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

Is it possible to open the Windows File Explorer from the command line on Windows?

There is something similar in OSX where `open .` opens the Finder window on the current folder path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either `start .` or `explorer .` will open Explorer in the current folder.

From PowerShell it's `Invoke-Item .`, `ii .`, or also `explorer .`.